# JavaScript error anonymous function

Tags: javascript, object

I have something like this

```
if(window.Test==null)
{
    window.Test = {};
    Test.usrTZ = Test.getTZ( new Date().getTimezoneOffset() );

    Test.getTZ = function(offset)
    {
     .....
     return offset;
    };

}
```

The line `Test.usrTZ = Test.getTZ( new Date().getTimezoneOffset() );`  throws in Chrome an error `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"`. I in general use traditional object notation, but want to learn how to use this one. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here - any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `Test.getTZ` before you have defined it.